# Is Identity Core 2 IdentityRole missing defintions for Users?

Tags: identity, asp.net-core-2.0

Am I missing something or has the definition for Users been removed from `IdentityRole` in Identity Core 2?

I am using asp.net core 2 and I need to calculate the number of users per role. This worked just fine in Core 1 with the following standard code

```cs
public class ApplicationRoleController : Controller
{
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager;    
    public ApplicationRoleController(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ApplicationRoleListViewModel> model = new List<ApplicationRoleListViewModel>();
        model = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new
        {
            RoleName = r.Name,
            Id = r.Id,
            Description = r.Description,
            NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count
        }).ToList()
        .Select(r => new ApplicationRoleListViewModel
        {
            RoleName = r.RoleName,
            Id = r.Id,
            Description = r.Description,
            NumberOfUsers = r.NumberOfUsers
        }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

In My application using Core 2, the line `NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count`, where r is derived from the class `ApplicationRole` with the error that "ApplicationRole does not contain a definition for Users" The `ApplicationRole` inherits from `IdentityRole`.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `IdentityRole` has never had a `Users` property. The relationship between roles and users was always defined via the entity `IdentityUserRole`, which had foreign keys to each, but also no navigation properties.

Comment: @Chriss Thanks for the comment.. But why does the code work with Core 1 and stops working within core 2? I remain baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
var admins = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin").Result;
var number = admins.Count;
```

The issue with Core 2 apparently is that they forgo the navigation properties in 
AspNetUsers AspNetUserRoles AspNetRoles. No idea why. Its very frustrating to be honest. Supposedly you can re-implement them, but so far I had no luck. I am here trying to find a way to list all users with all their roles.
I think the above code is what you need tho.

Also _userManager is imported as such in a controller

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;


    public MyControllerController(DBContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.context = context;
        _userManager = userManager; ;
    }
```